# Find the value of $\int \left(\frac{3x^2-9x+1}{3x^3-3x+3}\right)^2dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, factoring, fractions

**Question:**

Find the  value of $\displaystyle \int \left(\frac{3x^2-9x+1}{3x^3-3x+3}\right)^2dx$.

**Attempt:**

$\displaystyle I = \int\left(\frac{x^2-3x+3^{-1}}{x^3-x+1}\right)^2dx$

Want to be able to go further, someone help me, thanks.

Comment: now you must use a parfrac decomposition of the denominator. The result looks ugly

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{-9 x^2+27 x-26}{9 \left(x^3-x+1\right)}$$

Comment: This calculator suggested to Apply Ostrogradsky's method: https://goo.gl/EwZ4rG

Comment: The value of an indefinite integral? Are you looking for a primitive or a value (like $\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(x) dx$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{3x^3-3x+3}\right)}{dx}=\dfrac{(2Ax+B)(3x^3-3x+3)-(Ax^2+Bx+C)(9x^2-3)}{(3x^3-3x+3)^2}$$

$(3x^2-9x+1)^2=(2Ax+B)(3x^3-3x+3)-(Ax^2+Bx+C)(9x^2-3)$

$\iff9x^4-54x^3+90x^2-18x+1=(6A-9A)x^4+x^3(3B-6A-9B)+x^2(\cdots)+x(\cdots)+3B+3C$

Compare the constants and the  coefficients of $x^4,x^3$ to find $A,B,C$

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify $$I =\int (\frac {3x^2-9x+1}{3x^3-3x+3})^2 dx = \frac {1}{9} \int \frac {(3x^2-9x+1)^2}{(x^3-x+1)^2} dx = \frac {1}{9} I_1$$

To calculate $I_1$, we use the [Ostrogadsky method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ostrogradski_method). For the procedure to be used, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081525/integrating-int-frac5x44x5x5x12dx).

---

For our integral we have, $$P (x)= (3x^2-9x+1)^2 $$ $$Q (x)=(x^3-x+1)^2$$ $$Q'(x)=2 (3x^2-1)(x^3-x+1) $$ $$Q_1(x)=Q_2 (x)=x^3-x+1$$ We then get the polynomials $$P_1 (x)= -9x^2+27x-26 \text {  and   } P_2 (x)= 0$$

---

Thus, $$I_1 =-\frac{9x^2-27x+26}{x^3-x+1} $$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Its x^3 below can you explain first step

Answer (score 1):

$\int\frac{(3x^2-9x+1)^2}{(3x^3-3x+3)^2}dx=-\frac{1}{9}\frac{9x^2-27x+26}{x^3-x+1}+C$

Because $(18x-27)(x^3-x+1)-(9x^2-27x+26)(3x^2-1)=-(3x^2-9x+1)^2$.